# Why is a Zariski closed set compact under the Zariski topology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, compactness, zariski-topology

The book "Invitation to Algebraic Geometry" says the following:

> A Zariski closed set in $\Bbb{A}^n$ is compact in the Zariski topology.

Why is this this the case? According to the Hilbert Basis Theorem, I can understand that any open cover of the **complement** of a variety will have a finite subcover. But I don't understand why an open cover of a variety will have a finite subcover.

Comment: It is *quasi*-compact.

Answer (score 4):

Let $Z\subset\mathbb{A}^n=X$ a closed subset; by definition
$$
\exists f_1,\dots,f_r\in\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dots,x_n]=R\mid Z=V(f_1,\dots,f_r)=\bigcap_{i=1}^rV(f_r),
$$
withous loss of the generality we can assume $r=1$ and we put $f_1=f$ so that $Z=V(f)$; because $R$ is an U.F.D., then
\begin{gather*}
\exists g_1,\dots,g_s\in R\mid f=g_1\cdot\dots\cdot g_s,\,g_j\,\text{is a prime polynomial}\\
Z=V(g_1\cdot\dots\cdot g_s)=\bigcup_{j=1}^sV(g_j),
\end{gather*}
without loss of generality we can assume $s=1$, in other words $f$ is a prime polynomial and $Z$ is an irreducible closed subset of $X$.

Let $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ an open covering of $Z$, for exact:
$$
Z\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i,
$$
by previous reasoning, we can assume (without loss of the generality) that $U_i$'s are irreducible; by definition:
\begin{gather*}
\forall i\in I,\exists f_i\in R\mid U_i=D(f_i)=X\setminus V(f_i),\\
\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i=\dots=X\setminus\bigcap_{i\in I}V(f_i)=X\setminus W;
\end{gather*}
we know that $W$ is a closed subset of $X$, let $I(W)$ be the associated ideal of $W$, by Hilbert's Base theorem, it is finitely generated; by this statement
\begin{gather*}
\exists I_F\subseteq I\,\text{finite,}\,\{f_i\in R\}_{i\in I_F}\mid I(W)=(f_i\mid i\in I_F)\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow Z\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i=X\setminus V(I(W))=X\setminus\bigcap_{i\in I_F}V(f_i)=\bigcup_{i\in I_F}U_i
\end{gather*}
and the claims follows. (*Q.E.D.*) $\Box$

**Remark:** I had use only the hypothesys that $X$ is an affine space over a field, independently from its characteristic and other algebraic properties!

Comment: What is $D(f_i)$?

Comment: Sorry me, I wrote $U_i=D(f_i)=X\setminus V(f_i)$; or in other words, *by definition* $D(f_i)$ *is equal to* $X\setminus V(f_i)$!

Comment: How do you gurantee that $W$ will be generated by a finite subset of $\{f_i\}$? It will be generated by a finite collection for sure by Hilbert basis theorem, but why that will be a finite subset of $\{f_i\}$?

Comment: $I(W)$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, so it is a finitely generated ideal by _Hilbert's Base Theorem_; because $W$ is closed then $W=\overline{W}=V(I(W))$. Is it more clear?

Comment: I have mentioned in my comment that it will be generated by a finite collection by Hilbert base theorem(this part is clear). My question is why that finite collection has to be a finite subset of $\{f_i\}_{i \in I}$? It can be any other finite subcollection, right! say $\{g_1,...,g_n\} \nsubseteq \{f_i\}_{i \in I}$.

Comment: By Noetherianess; indeed, one has an ascending chain of ideals $(f_1)\subsetneqq(f_1,f_2)\subsetneqq\dots\subsetneqq\mathcal{I}(W)$, because this must be a finite chain one has $\mathcal{I}(W)=(f_1,\dots,f_N)$ for some integer $N>0$.

Answer (score 1):

A Zariski closed set in $A^n$ is a  noetherian space. Thus it is compact.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_topological_space

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $V$ is closed and additionally *irreducible* and covered by $\bigcup _{i\in I}U_i$, pick $x\in V$ and then $i\in I$ with $x\in U_i$. Then $V\setminus U_i$ is closed and of lower dimension.

Comment: I'm no sure I understand what "of lower dimension" means. Are you using a form of induction on a cover that could possibly be infinite to begin with?

Comment: Oh okay. I guess you're using the fact that a closed set in he Zariski topology is Noetherian.