# The complement of a point in $\Bbb{A}^n$ is compact in the Zariski topology.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, compactness, affine-geometry, affine-varieties

The book "Invitation to Algebraic Geometry" says the following:

> The complement of a point in $\Bbb{A}^n$ is compact in the Zariski topology.

Why is this this the case? This is thing that is asked in the commutative algebra section so I hope that Hilbert basis theorem might be used. Do we have to take a closure of the complement space?

Can we extend this to a question that 
**any open cover of the complement of a variety will have a finite subcover?**

Comment: You can try to see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938690/why-is-a-zariski-closed-set-compact-under-the-zariski-topology/1940667#1940667).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is going to sound crazy, but:

> *Every subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$ is compact*.

The reason is almost purely set-theoretic, and here it is.

People call a topological space $X$ a **noetherian space** if it satisfies the ascending chain condition on open sets (equivalently, the DCC on closed sets). Notice $\mathbb{A}^n$ is noetherian, in fact any variety (irreducible or not) is noetherian --- this is basically because the coordinate ring is a finitely-generated algebra over a field, which is a noetherian ring, and closed sets in $\mathbb{A}^n$ correspond to ideals of these rings.

Here is the important exercise.

> **Great fact:** *$X$ is noetherian if and only if every subset of $X$ is compact.*

Since $\mathbb{A}^n$ is noetherian, this answers your question!

Comment: Yes you are right!! My bad I missed that observation